# Django email is giving error ''list' object has no attribute 'splitlines''

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-email

This is my email sending code in my view:

```
def send_email():
    if dasa == 1:
        send_mail(
            'Test available',
            available_tests,
            'from_email',
            ['to_email'],
            fail_silently=False,
        )
```

When I run it on the website, though, I get this error:

```
AttributeError at /tests/
'list' object has no attribute 'splitlines'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    https://myapp.herokuapp.com/tests/
Django Version: 4.0.1
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'list' object has no attribute 'splitlines'
Exception Location: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py, line 169, in set_payload
Python Executable:  /app/.heroku/python/bin/python
Python Version: 3.9.10
Python Path:    
['/app/.heroku/python/bin',
 '/app',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python39.zip',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages']
Server time:    Fri, 18 Feb 2022 03:06:30 +0000
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view
/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py, line 47, in inner
                response = get_response(request) …
Local vars
/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py, line 181, in _get_response
                response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) …
Local vars
/app/Tests/views.py, line 35, in check
        send_mail('Test available', available_tests, 'from_email@gmail.com', ['to_email@gmail.com'], fail_silently=False) …
Local vars
/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/mail/__init__.py, line 61, in send_mail
    return mail.send() …
Local vars
/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py, line 284, in send
        return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self]) …
Local vars
/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py, line 109, in send_messages
                sent = self._send(message) …
Local vars
/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py, line 123, in _send
        message = email_message.message() …
Local vars
/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py, line 246, in message
        msg = SafeMIMEText(self.body, self.content_subtype, encoding) …
Local vars
/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py, line 159, in __init__
        MIMEText.__init__(self, _text, _subtype=_subtype, _charset=_charset) …
Local vars
/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/email/mime/text.py, line 42, in __init__
Local vars
/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py, line 169, in set_payload
                for line in payload.splitlines()
```

How can I fix it? I took the instructions straight from a django tutorial, so I don't know why it isn't working. I also can't find anything on what this supposed 'splitlines' attribute is.

Comment: What is `available_tests` variable?

Comment: Please post the complete error trace

Comment: @Dauros its a list

Comment: @Razenstein Posted the full traceback

Comment: available_tests needs to be a string!

Comment: @Razenstein Oh! Thanks! I don't know why I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django's [`send_email`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/email/#send-mail) expects a string as the message argument. So you need to apply e.g. `join` on the `available_tests` list variable first. Depending the structure of the variable, a simple `"\n".join(available_tests)` can be enough. Or `<br>` if you have HTML message.

Comment: I would put 'available_tests.join()' in the send field?

Comment: The message is the second argument of `send_mail`, where you have `available_tests` list now. The [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) expects an iterable as an argument. So if you replace the second argument with `"\n".join(available_tests)` that joins the list with new line character, then it should be fine (assuming you have simple strings in the list).